# How to allow a url with disallow arbitrary HTTP method rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added a rule in htaccess file to disallow arbitrary HTTP method as below :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|PUT|OPTIONS|DELETE|HEAD)
RewriteRule .*$ - [F,L]
```

But all custom page showing 404 page not found, I want to allow to access only one page say `test.php`.

For this I tried to add below condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|PUT|OPTIONS|DELETE|HEAD)
RewriteRule .*$ - [F,L]
```

But it is not working.

What condition should I add to allow one `.php` page?

Comment: I would recon those requests are simply not routed through mod_rewrite. Consider using LimitExcept (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept)

Comment: Please post here how to use `LimitExcept` with particular one url.

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` string starts with a leading  slash. so change 
your condition line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test\.php$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test\.php$
```

Comment: What folder is your test.php file located in?

Comment: `test.php` is in root folder, when I comment above rule then it is accessible.

Comment: Try changing your rule to `RewriteRule !test\.php$ - [F,L]`